# get output 'during' a long foreach loop - not just at the end of last item in loop

Tags: php, foreach, continue

i have a long hours working foreach loop which outputs correctly at the end when all items are processed..

```
    foreach ($matches[0] as $map_link) {
    if ($map_link!='' && $i < $max_tags ) {
        include('reg-process.php');
    }

    $i++;
    }
```

infact for each $matches[0] which are over 600 matches it includes the 
'reg-process.php' page which processes each match in turn and after over one hour it finishes and outputs all results ..
what i need is not to wait till the last item to see results, so while the loop is working after each item is processed it could be echoed.. 
so again i need every time the loop includes 'reg-process.php' page print out 
the result , not to wail up to the last item then all print out at once.. something like continue?

Comment: This will *help*, but will not totally solve your problem (which is not actually solve-able).  **Inside your loop**, after your include, add this line: `ob_flush();` - it will cause PHP to push the output to the browser.  It's not going to be perfect, but it will help.  **NOTE:** This is not a good way to go - you should not `include` inside of a loop, but rather you should turn that code (in `reg-process.php`) into a *function* and call that function inside of the loop.

Comment: so brilliant man , i don't know what's your code but it worked.. well maybe not exactly  after each item's loop but like after every 10 items loop it echos out the result and appends to the end of screen,  very simple and perfect to me. so for a 600 items loop which will take more than an hour now i can study some results while the loop is working for next items.

Answer (score 0):

[include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) shouldn't be used in the way you use it, it should be used to include functionality or reduce single file complexity rather than to misuse it as a function. So first of all, get rid of the include as this will lead to problems at some point in time (i.e. you can't include one file multiple times in case it contains functions).

There are different ways to get what you want, here are just two possibilities:

1.) File-based logging:

```
<?php
// file: register_process.php
function registerProgress($map_link) 
{
  // YOUR CODE 
  // ...
  // assuming that the result of your code is a string variable that can be logged
  file_put_contents('registration.log', $logResult, FILE_APPEND);
}

include('register_progress.php');    

foreach ($matches[0] as $map_link) {
  if ($map_link!='' && $i < $max_tags ) {
      registerProgress($map_link);
  }
  $i++;
}
```

2.) Switch to ajax:

in case you are running the script as part of a web application (rather than as console application), you could rewrite your code to execute one page request per map link.

Advantages: you'll get a visible result per executed call, reduced script memory usage, lesser risk of timeouts (due to PHP, webserver or browser timeouts).

Disadvantages: increased page requests and code refactoring required.

`ob_flush()` will not work as browsers do not parse content of a pending page request; instead you would have to use a network sniffer to read the partial flushed content.

Comment: nice I'm sure both of your suggestions will work , just i remember my lazy thoughts was like your answers but i forgot them during development in hope there will be something like 'continue' to do it very simple.. nice idea and informative person.. by the way why people give the question negative  scores? please if somebody can't get the question please please do not give it negative marks!!

Comment: @ShahramMohseni: IMHO your question is being downvoted because it represents an example of bad coding/bad practices and people don't want other users to pick it up for their code. Just my two cents ...

Answer (score -1):

You are not following foreach format with proper syntax. The ideal code are follows-

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
```

Make sure that, **$matches[0]** is an array. Without array, it will not work. Just rewrite your code, hope will work properly.

Comment: ok, on your example when it is finished it will output or retrun all $arr items correctly .. what i need is not to wait for 600 items in $arr so after every cycle try to outputs .. somthing like continue?